# HTML, CSS & JS Animate Multiple Progress bars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

So I'm trying to animate multiple progress bars on one page, here is the HTML for my progress bars:

```
<div class="col-md-5">
  <p>HTML & CSS</p>
  <div class="progress progress-striped active">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" style="width: 50%;"></div>
  </div>
  <p>C#</p>
  <div class="progress progress-striped active">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" style="width: 20%;"></div>
  </div>
  <p>WordPress</p>
  <div class="progress progress-striped active">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" style="width: 30%;"></div>
  </div>
  <p>Photoshop</p>
  <div class="progress progress-striped active">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" style="width: 20%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am also using this code in my CSS Styling

```
.progress.active .progress-bar {
   -webkit-transition: none !important;
   transition: none !important;
 }
```

And this is my JS function:

```
$(".progress-bar").animate({width: "10%"}, 2500);
```

Using this, all 4 bars are animated, but I'd like to animate each bar with a different value.

Answer (score 4):

You can target the individual bars using `.eq()` which takes an index as a parameter to specify which bar you want.

```
$(".progress-bar").eq(0); // First bar
$(".progress-bar").eq(1); // Second bar
```

From here, just call the animate method on the selected element. Storing the initial `$(".progress-bar")` call is also considered good practice.

```
var $bars = $(".progress-bar");
$bars.eq(0).animate({width: "10%"}, 2500);
$bars.eq(1).animate({width: "5%"}, 2500);
```

Answer (score -2):

this way you can also do it.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".progress-bar").each(function (index ) {
        if(index >=0 && index<=1)
        {
            $(this).animate({width: "5%"}, 2500);
        }
    })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/80cww0qr/

we can also increase progress bar randomly whose value will be between 1 to 100

```
$(this).animate({width: Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1) + "%"}, 2500);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/80cww0qr/1/